# PowerShell: Match string, add text end of line in multiple files

Tags: powershell

I have multiple files in a folder that I am trying to match a string "Name=" and then add some text at the end of the line "AREA:...".  The code is working, however, it is putting ALL contents of ALL files into each file.  I understand I need to iterate through each file, but I am struggling with using a loop for the match and then loop each file so it doesn't add all contents.  I am very new to PowerShell and I appreciate any help and your patients.  Thank you

```
$filepaths = 'C:\Users\test\test\*.txt' 

foreach ($filename in $filepaths)
{
   (Get-Content $filename) |
    foreach {          
        if ($_ -match "Name=")
        {            
             "$_   AREA:   KIT:"             
        }
        else
        {
            $_
        }                          
       } | set-Content $filename
}
```

Thanks to AdminOfThings the following code is working

```
$filepaths = 'C:\Users\test\test\*.txt' 

foreach ($filename in (get-item $filepaths))
{
   (Get-Content $filename) |
    foreach {          
        if ($_ -match "Name=")
        {            
             "$_   AREA:   KIT:"             
        }
        else
        {
            $_
        }                          
       } | set-Content $filename
}
```

Comment: use a `foreach` loop to iterate over the files. look at `Get-Help about_Foreach` for some nifty examples. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for commenting Lee, I have edited the code for the Foreach command, but the result is the same.  Again I am new to PowerShell and I have been trying to figure out the answer with examples from the Get-help, but with no luck.

Comment: `$filepaths` is a single string that happens to be a path with a wildcard character. It is not your files. `get-content` can accept wildcards in its `path` parameter. This makes your one `get-content` return all contents of all txt files. Powershell will enumerate all lines from that single array and process each line in the pipeline. So you get every line output to one file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need set string to any string that contains in any order "Name=" you must did like this:

```
$filepaths = 'C:\Users\test\test\*.txt'     
foreach ($filename in (get-item $filepaths)){
  (Get-Content $filename) |foreach {          
    if ($_ -match "Name="){            
    $_.Insert($_.Length," AREA:   KIT:")         
    }
    else{
    $_
    }                          
  } | set-Content $filename
}
```